# Reports - Export Report In Group using powerbi API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Hi I am using the powerbi api provided by the developer team. There are bunches of api related to export and import of dashboard, reports, workbooks and datasets. All APIs are working fine but the Exporting of report is throwing 404 not found error.

The target API is
 https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/b7a888be-fcf3-4abd-b95c-2972171bc480/reports/9a8bef1b-e5b5-4504-a7db-17185f2703f0/Export

The error I am getting in postman is 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExportPBIX_ModelessWorkbookNotFound",
        "pbi.error": {
            "code": "ExportPBIX_ModelessWorkbookNotFound",
            "parameters": {},
            "details": []
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Not all reports can be exported. For example, it may be created directly in the browser (instead of publishing from Power BI Desktop), or the export is disabled by your administrator. When you open this report in the browser, can you export it from File -> Download report or it is disabled?
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-export-to-pbix#considerations-and-troubleshooting) is the full list of requirement for a report to be exportable:

- To download the file, you must have edit access to the report
- The report must have been created using Power BI Desktop and been published to the Power BI service, or the .pbix must have been uploaded to the service.
- Reports must be published or updated after November 23, 2016. Reports published prior to then are not downloadable.
- This feature will not work with reports originally created in the Power BI service, including content packs.
- You should always be using the latest version of Power BI Desktop when opening downloaded files. Downloaded .pbix files may not open in non-current versions of Power BI Desktop.
- If your administrator has turned off the ability to export data, this feature will not be visible in the Power BI service.
- Dataset with incremental refresh can't be downloaded to a .pbix file.

Comment: How about reports that are Cloned to a new Push Dataset? 
I am currently getting this error: 
`"code": "ExportPBIX_ModelessWorkbookNotFound",`